# Solving a system of semilinear coupled partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I would like to know if it is possible to find the solution to the following system of partial differential equations:
\begin{equation}
\partial_x \mathbf{u}+B(x,y) \cdot \partial_y \mathbf{u}-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{u},x,y)=0
\end{equation}

Where $\mathbf{f,u}\in \rm{I \!R}^{n}$, $B\in \rm{I \!R}^{(n\times n)}$, $x,y \in \rm{I \!R}$

Especially if this is possible by using the method of characteristics.
Related is this answer on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193330/method-of-characteristics-of-a-system-of-first-order-pdes). In a comment there the  'the method of Darboux' is stated for some nonlinear equations.

Question are:

- Is the Method of characteristics applicable for coupled semilinear pdes?
- Does the method of Darboux always work for semilinear pdes?
- If neither is applicable in general how would one solve these equations?

Comment: Two comments that do not address the question,but the post: First TeX for  $\Bbb R$ is `\mathbb R` or for short, `\Bbb R`. Second. $\mathbf {f, u, B}$, are *not* elements of the sets as indicated, but rather *maps* from some region $U \subset \Bbb R^2$ into these sets: $f : U \to \Bbb R^n, B : U \to \Bbb R^{(n \times n)}, u : U \to \Bbb R^n$. Also, if you want to find out how someone produced some piece of formatting, right-click on it, and choose "Show Math As" --> "TeX Commands".

Comment: Thanks for the tex hint and also thanks for clarifying it!
Do you have any idea hints regarding the question? :)